# Swift: different objects with same properties: hash value

Tags: swift, hash

Currently I have a class of generic type, and I want to make the object of this class searchable via

```
contains()
```

method for an array of those objects, by making the class conform to Hashable protocol and provide a hash value for each object. Now my problem is I have objects with exactly the same properties, and it seems that the array cannot really distinguish them (my current approach is to use one of the properties' hash value as the hash value for the class, and the

```
== <T> (lhs: ClassA<T>, rhs: ClassA<T>) -> Bool
```

function is done by comparing the hash value). I have tried to use a static property like "id", but for generic types static properties are not supported.

How should I define the hash value such that different objects with the same properties can still be differentiated?

**EDIT:** I'm making it conform to Hashable directly because it's also used as keys in dict in other parts of the program, since Hashable already conforms to Equatable.

Comment: If you want two different objects with equal properties not to be equal, you can add an identifier (e.g. autoincrementing id for new objects) to distuinguish them or just use their pointer value (for class types).

Answer (score 2):

> My current approach is to use one of the properties' hash value as the
>   hash value for the class, and the
>
> ```
> == <T> (lhs: ClassA<T>, rhs: ClassA<T>) -> Bool
> ```
>
> function is done by comparing the hash value

That's not how the `==` and `hashValue` relationship works – don't do this. What if you get a hash collision? Two different instances with different properties could compare equal.

You should instead implement `==` to *actually compare* the properties of two instances. `==` should return `true` if two given instances have equivalent properties. The `hashValue`s of two instances should be equivalent if they compare equal with `==`.

Now, it might well be the case that you cannot do this comparison unless `T` is `Equatable`. One solution to this is to not conform `ClassA` to `Equatable`, but instead just overload `==` for when `T` is `Equatable`, such as:

```
func == <T : Equatable>(lhs: ClassA<T>, rhs: ClassA<T>) -> Bool {
    // stub: do comparison logic
}
```

You can now just use `Sequence`'s [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/2297500-contains) method in conjunction with the `==` overload in order to check if a given instance is in the array:

```
var array = [ClassA("foo")] // assuming ClassA has an init(_: T) and a suitable ==
                            // implementation to compare that value

let someInstanceToFind = ClassA("foo")
print(array.contains { $0 == someInstanceToFind }) // true
```

And if you want `ClassA` to have a `hashValue`, then simply write an `extension` that defines a `hashValue` when `T` is `Hashable`:

```
extension ClassA where T : Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return 0 // to do: implement hashValue logic
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does mean that `ClassA` won't explicitly conform to `Hashable` when `T` does – but it will have a `hashValue` and `==` implementation. [SE-0143: Conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) will change this by allowing explicit conformance to protocols if a given `where` clause if satisfied, but this is yet to be implemented.

If you need explicit conformance to `Hashable` (such as for using instances of your class in a `Set` or as `Dictionary` keys) – then one solution is to create a wrapper type:

```
struct HashableClassA<T : Hashable> : Hashable {

    var base: ClassA<T>

    init(_ base: ClassA<T>) {
        self.base = base
    }

    static func ==(lhs: HashableClassA, rhs: HashableClassA) -> Bool {
        return lhs.base == rhs.base
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return base.hashValue
    }
}
```

Now you just have to wrap `ClassA<T>` instances in a `HashableClassA` instance before adding to a `Set` or `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized there is a simple way for achieving the Equatable in

```
contains()
```

method: use

```
return lhs === rhs
```

in the == function such that objects are compared directly. It's working in this way now.

Comment: Note that this may lead to surprising results with two different instances which *look like* they should be equivalent – but aren't because they aren't the *same* instance.